# The first female algebraist in US/Britain?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, ho.history-overview

Recently I dug up some biographical details of Lindsay Burch, of [Hilbert-Burch Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Burch_theorem) fame, whose few papers have had quite an impact on commutative algebra. This made me curious about the first women who obtained PhDs in abstract algebra in the US and Britain.

> Question 1: Who was the first woman to get a PhD in the US on a topic in algebra?

Potential answer: [Mildred Sanderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildred_Sanderson), who obtained her PhD from Dickson in 1913 (published in Annals of Mathematics), and tragically died one year later. I found her name in Bell's ["50 years of algebra in America, 1888-1938"](https://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/math-history/procsemi-bell.pdf). Is that correct?

For Britain, I could not find any similar information. Burch got her PhD in 1967 under David Rees, but surely other women got British PhDs in algebra earlier. So:

> Question 2: Who was the first woman to get a PhD in Great Britain on a topic in algebra?

Comment: Not really an algebraist, and definitely not the first, but if you're interested in early female math Ph.D.s in the US, then you may be interested in [Mary Leonius Schulte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Leontius_Schulte), a nun who earned hers in 1935.  (Based on the title, it seems to be perhaps more history of math than math proper.)

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte_Scott, Charlotte Scott studied under Cayley and so is a plausible candidate, although I can't seem to find the subject of her dissertation.

Comment: @LSpice: that's very interesting. Of course, Sanderson got hers in 1913, quite earlier. I am not sure I understand your last sentence. Are we not supposed to ask history question now? (I have not been active on MO the last couple of years).

Comment: I believe he meant that her dissertation was on History of Mathematics.

Comment: @ToddEisworth is [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386109/the-first-female-algebraist-in-us-britain#comment984345_386109).  Thanks for the clarification!  (I *would* like to see more history of mathematics questions go to the specialised site [HSMSE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com), but I am in the minority in this opinion.)

Comment: @SamHopkins ... and Charlotte Scott went on to supervise an early one in the U.S. (Emilie Martin, [1899](https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=6972)).

Comment: At a minimum, one needs to mention Emmy Noether in this theme.

Comment: Try to look in the book "Pioneering Women in American Mathematics: The Pre-1940 PhD's" for potential answers to the USA part of your question, but Francois's answer from 1889 seems like it will be hard to beat.

Comment: Algebra before Noethers was quite different than algebra today. One can consider Ruth Gentry (PhD 1896) an algebraist too, https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=6964.

Comment: @KConrad: thanks, that's a helpful reference, I will take a look.

Comment: @HailongDao  History of Math questions may be asked in https://hsm.stackexchange.com the forum on ... "History of Science and Mathematics".

Comment: @SamHopkins Looking up Scott's details on Wikipedia, it's not clear to me if there was an actual PhD thesis as such. Of course, in terms of academic merit this is merely splitting hairs, but if one is singling out the PhD as a particular badge then her case might be too early to qualify

Comment: @WlodAA: we all know about Emmy Noether. What is surprising from this discussion (to me at least) is that the US produced female PhDs in algebra before Noether (who did her PhD in 1907).

Comment: @HailongDao: Everybody knows Noether. In particular everybody knows that she defended her PhD in 1907 only because she was not allowed to do it earlier.

Comment: @dodd: really? Noether was 25 in 1907, so it seemed not too delayed. Her advisor Gordan got his PhD at same age. In any case many women on the US list were delayed too.

Comment: @HailongDao: Really. Noether does not qualify for the answer because she was not in the UK/USA. On the other hand without her and her father we would not have modern Algebra. In this sense women PhDs  before Noether do not qualify because they were not algebraists in modern sense.

Comment: Since many universities did not grant degrees to women in past centuries, maybe the PhD requirement should be dropped. Actually, [Wikipedia's *Timeline of Women's Education*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Women's_education) says two Italian women got doctorates the 17th century.

Answer (score 16):

I think a very honourable mention is the American [Ida May Schottenfels](https://www.agnesscott.edu/lriddle/women/schottenfels.htm), who did not receive a PhD, but who nevertheless was very active in mathematical research:

> Ida May Schottenfels graduated from Northwestern University with a Bachelor of Arts degree in 1892. She then studied at Yale and the University of Chicago, earning a Masters degree in mathematics from Chicago in 1896. [...]  In 1910 she was appointed head of the department of mathematics in Toledo University.  In their study of "Women in the American Mathematical Research Community: 1891-1906" Fenster and Parshall cite Schottenfels as one of the two most "active" participants (along with Charlotte Angas Scott), listing her as giving 17 talks at mathematics conferences, publishing 3 papers, and attending 23 meetings and/or colloquia including those of the American Mathematical Society.

She was also the first mathematician to prove that there are two finite simple groups of the same order (namely of order $20160$). So although she did not receive a PhD, she surely seems to have deserved one!

Comment: Thanks, I definitely agree.

Answer (score 15):

I followed the reference suggested by KConrad in the comments and found perhaps the answer to Question 1:

[Annie MacKinnon](https://www.agnesscott.edu/lriddle/women/fitch.htm), who got her PhD from Cornell in 1894 with the thesis "Concomitant Binary Forms in Terms of the Roots" (invariant theory). The published version (Annals of Mathematics, 1894 - 1895, Vol. 9, No. 1/6 (1894 - 1895), pp. 95-157) can be found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1967513.pdf).

As for Question 2, perhaps one can nominate [Charlotte Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte_Scott) as suggested in the comments, although from circumstantial evidence she probably did her thesis on geometry of plane curves, so I am still wondering if there is a more "algebraic" thesis later.

Answer (score 10):

[Christine Ladd-Franklin](https://www.agnesscott.edu/lriddle/women/ladd.htm) had her dissertation published but did not receive her PhD:

> At Johns Hopkins Ladd developed her interest in symbolic logic through the lectures of Charles Sanders Peirce, writing a dissertation on "The Algebra of Logic" and publishing several more articles in The Analyst. However, Johns Hopkins did not allow women to receive the Ph.D. degree, so Ladd left the school in 1882 without that official recognition. Her dissertation, however, appeared in the volume Studies in Logic by Members of the Johns Hopkins University, edited by Charles S. Pierce, Little, Brown & Co., 1883 (pages 17-71).

(Not an answer, and too long for a comment, but still relevant to the question, in my humble opinion. I'm supposing, by the title of her dissertation, that it has something to do with algebra.)

Comment: Thanks, certainly a very interesting story. Looking at Charles Peirce's [papers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2369442), it seemed like her thesis would be on logic.

Comment: @HailongDao In connection to Peirce, the “algebra of logic” is simply Boolean algebra. It’s not possible to tell just from the title whether the thesis is oriented more on logic or on the underlying algebra.

Comment: [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_V7oIAAAAQAAJ/page/n25/mode/2up) seems to have Ladd's paper

Answer (score 9):

A few early 20th century US Ph.D.'s (the first three are before Mildred Sanderson, but after Annie MacKinnon):

- Ph.D. 1906 Bryn Mawr: [Virginia Ragsdale](https://www.agnesscott.edu/LRiddle/women/ragsdale.htm), *On the Arrangement of the Real Branches of Plane Algebraic
  Curves*
- Ph.D. 1909 Univ. Chicago: [Anna
  Johnson Pell Wheeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Johnson_Pell_Wheeler), *Biorthogonal Systems of Functions with
  Applications to the Theory of Integral Equations*
  <sub>It was Wheeler who brought Emmy Noether to Bryn Mawr in 1933, after her expulsion from Göttingen University.</sub>
- Ph.D. 1911 UC Berkeley: [Annie
  Dale Biddle Andrews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annie_Dale_Biddle_Andrews), *Constructive theory of the unicursal plane
  quartic by synthetic methods*
- Ph.D. 1915 Univ. Chicago: [Olive Hazlett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive_Hazlett),
  *On the Classification and Invariantive Characterization of Nilpotent
  Algebras*

Two late 19th century US Ph.D.'s who shared the advisor with Annie MacKinnon (although their research topic might not quite fit the algebra tag):

- Ph.D. 1893 Cornell: [Ida Martha Metcalf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ida_Martha_Metcalf), *Geometric Duality in Space*
- Ph.D. 1895 Cornell:
  [Agnes Sime Baxter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnes_Sime_Baxter), *Abelian Integrals*